# How can I remove chrome cache in android pragmatically

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, root, browser-cache

I tried to remove it using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps clear com.android.chrome");` but it will return `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied` after I tried it with rooted phone but it also getting same error. after that I use File handling to remove `/data/data/com.android.chrome` but it also getting same error

Android version is 7.0

is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

First You need to root your Android device properly

after that

follow this instruction below

add this to the dependency in  **build.gradle** (app)

```
`implementation 'eu.chainfire:libsuperuser:1.0.0.+'`
```

then

call this method form `Shell` in your action method

```
Shell.run("su",new String[]{"pm clear com.android.chrome"},true);
```

or

```
Shell.SU.run("pm clear com.android.chrome");
```

it will properly working latest android version too

I'll guarantee to you it will work from android 6.0 to latest